# rails/rspec how to get the response when making a post request with body to API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm building a Rails backend API and i have a controller that receives post requests. I'm using rspec to make a call to the endpoint and so far it looks like it working. However i am unable to visualise my response. (the controller works and renders the correct JSON). My spec looks like this:

```
require "spec_helper"
require "rspec_api_documentation/dsl"

resource "Data" do
  header "Accept", "application/json"
  header "Content-Type", "application/json"
  header "Host", "public.example.com"

  describe "receives POST request with body", :type => :request do
    params = { type: ["1", "2", "3"], fromDate: "26/05/2015", toDate: "30/05/2015" }
    post "/api/v1/data/totals", params.to_json
  end
end
```

This test passes, but i don't seem to be able to retrieve the rendered JSON. i've tried putting the following in the describe block:

```
puts response_body
puts response.body
puts page.body
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Comment: should be a controller spec

Comment: Why, what does that change? I tried but i still get the same errors

Comment: in requests specs, you should only use `visit`, and then interact with the browser

Comment: Ok, but i still can't get a response even when i change to :controller

Comment: @apneadiving: "Capybara is no longer supported in
request specs as of Capybara 2.0.0." - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec

Comment: @AndyWaite ok I thought request specs were the same as feature specs. Not sure why rspec provides their so called `thin layer` since it ends up being used like a controller spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out with some help from a friend. This is the correct syntax with use of the rspec api documentation/dsl:

```
require "spec_helper"
require "rspec_api_documentation/dsl"

resource "Data" do
  header "Accept", "application/json"
  header "Content-Type", "application/json"
  header "Host", "public.example.com"

  describe "Post a request to totals" do
    parameter :type,"selected data type"
    parameter :fromDate, "start date"
    parameter :toDate, "end date"

    let(:type) { ["1", "2", "3"] }
    let(:fromDate) { "26/05/2015" }
    let(:toDate) { "30/05/2015" }

    post "/api/v1/data/totals" do
      let(:raw_post) { params.to_json }
      example_request "with a body" do
        expect(response_body).to include(fromDate, toDate)
        expect(status).to eq(200)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would if I could, have to wait 2 days. (well 1 hour now)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise there was a delay enforced.

Comment: might not be for people with a higher reputation :P but us newbies have to wait

Answer (score 1):

Within the `describe` block, your test needs to be within an `it` or `specify` block.

**Edit** - I see you're using the rspec_api_documentation gem. I'm not familiar with this, but it looks like you're mixing together two styles of syntax -- the gem's DSL, and RSpec's own DSL. The gem's README does not show `describe` being used. I would suggest sticking with plain RSpec until you get it passing, then try introduce the gem.

Comment: Would like to but i'm working on an existing project. Figured it out with some help though